# How to make the what happening box like twitter in our site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing this by taking the cursor position from the content-editable box. When a new tag is created the cursor comes before the tag but it should be after the tag. Also i am not able to merge/split the tag.
Please give some idea how can i do this.

```
Visit (https://plnkr.co/edit/DSHKEcOnBXi54KyiMpaT?p=preview) !
```

What i want here, after pressing the enter key for new tag the cursor should be at the end of tag while it is not and also the merging/spliting functionality like the twitter what's happening box.

Thanks in advance.

---

Now this code is working fr me

```
$scope.myIndexValue = "5";
            $scope.searchTag = function(term) {
                var tagList = [];
                angular.forEach($rootScope.tags, function(item) {
                    if (item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
                        tagList.push(item);
                    }
                });
                $scope.tag = tagList;
                return $q.when(tagList);
            };

            $scope.getTagText = function(item) {
                // note item.label is sent when the typedText wasn't found
                return '<a>#<i>' + (item.name || item.label) + '</i></a> ';
            };

            $scope.resetDemo = function() {
                // finally enter content that will raise a menu after everything is set up
                $timeout(function() {
                    //var html = "Tell us something about this or add a macro like brb, omw, (smile)";
                    var htmlContent = $element.find('#htmlContent');
                    var html = "";
                    if (htmlContent) {
                        var ngHtmlContent = angular.element(htmlContent);
                        ngHtmlContent.html(html);
                        ngHtmlContent.scope().htmlContent = html;
                        // select right after the #
                        mentioUtil.selectElement(null, htmlContent, [0], 8);
                        ngHtmlContent.scope().$apply();
                    }
                }, 0);
            };
```

HTML :

```
<div class="share_tags fs-12">
        <div class="row margin_row">
            <div class="col-md-12 no_padding">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div contenteditable="true" mentio
                         mentio-typed-term="typedTerm"
                         mentio-macros="macros"
                         mentio-require-leading-space="true"
                         mentio-select-not-found="true"
                         class="editor tag" placeholder="Tell Us something about This"
                         mentio-id="'htmlContent'"
                         id="htmlContent"
                         ng-model="htmlContent">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <mentio-menu
                        mentio-for="'htmlContent'"
                        mentio-trigger-char="'#'"
                        mentio-items="tag"
                        mentio-template-url="/people-mentions.tpl"
                        mentio-search="searchTag(term)"
                        mentio-select="getTagText(item)"
                        ></mentio-menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/people-mentions.tpl">
            <ul class="list-group user-search">
                <li mentio-menu-item="tag" ng-repeat="tag in items" class="list-group-item">
                    <span ng-bind-html="tag.name | mentioHighlight:typedTerm:'menu-highlighted' | unsafe"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </script>
    </div>
```

Reference link

```
http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation#/
```

is working fine for me.

---

This is not working perfectly but for the time being i am using this code.

In app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, $element) {
var tags;
$scope.allTags = ['Tag1', 'PrivateTag', 'Xtag', 'PublicTag1',       'newTag', 'socialTag', 'cricketTag'];
var replacedTag = '';
var replacedIndex;
var data;
$scope.log = function (name) {
    $scope.tags = [];
    $('ul').html(' ');
    console.log("here", $('ul'))
    var data = $('textarea').val();
    replacedIndex = data.indexOf(replacedTag)
    console.log('test', name, replacedTag, replacedIndex, data);
    var replacedData = data.substring(0, replacedIndex - 1) + ' #' + name + data.substr(replacedIndex + replacedTag.length);
    $('textarea').val(replacedData);
    $('textarea').keyup();
}
f = $scope.log;



$('textarea').on('keyup', function (e) {

  function getIndexOf(arr, val) {
  var l = arr.length,
    k = 0;
  for (k = 0; k < l; k = k + 1) {
    if (arr[k] === val) {
      return k;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
    $('ul').html('');
    $scope.tags = [];
    tags = $(this).val().match(/#\S+/g);
    console.log("---tags-", tags)

    var a = data = $(this).val();
    if (tags && tags.length) {
        tags.forEach(function (tag,index) {
          var index1 = getIndexOf(tags, tag);
          console.log("index----",index, index1,tag)


            replacedTag = tag;
            $scope.tags = tag ? $filter('filter')($scope.allTags, tag.substr(1)) : [];
            if ($scope.tags && $scope.tags.length && (e.keyCode && e.keCode != 32)) {
              $scope.tags.forEach(function (tag1, index) {
                    $('ul').append('<li>' + '<a href="javascript:;" onclick=f("' + tag1 + '");>'
                        + tag1 + '</a>' + '</li>')
                })
            }
            else {
              $('ul').html(' ');
            }
            if(index == index1) {
                var b = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(tag) - 1) + ' <a>' + tag + '</a> ' + a.substr(a.indexOf(tag) + tag.length);

            }
            else {

                var b = a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf(tag) - 1) + ' <a>' + tag + '</a> ' + a.substr(a.lastIndexOf(tag) + tag.length);

            }


            a = b;
            $('p').html(b)

        })
    }
})
```

});

HTML

```
    <br>
    <br>
    <p></p>

    <textarea rows="2" cols="80"></textarea>
    <div>
      <ul>

    </ul>

    </div>
```

For live demo Visit 
    https://plnkr.co/edit/SD9eouQa5yrViwxQD6yN?p=preview

i am also looking for the better answer.

Comment: Please provide some code you have already tried, it's very hard to answer questions like this without the context of your code.

Comment: Actually, i am using contenteditable rather than textarea as in textarea i can't replace the #tag data with anchor tag.            For my code please go through this link: https://plnkr.co/edit/DSHKEcOnBXi54KyiMpaT?p=preview i want the functionality same as the twitter's what's happening? box. But there is error when i merge or split the #tag data. I will be very thankfull to you if u could help me out.

Comment: Also i want a dropdown if some tags are there. In this  $scope.allTags variable contains all the tags. If a tag is already exist then i will select from tags else a new tag is created

Comment: For the person who down vote this: I am facing difficulty with this.  Dear Sir if this is a not a valid question for you then please help me out. As i am struggling with this and still not able to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about gathering hash tags from a string of sorts, the snippet below demonstrates how you can build an array of `#hashed` tags without modifying the cursor position.

It uses a simple `regular expression` to match tags found in the textarea and then pushes them to an array.

```js
var tags;

$('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
  tags = $(this).val().match(/#\S+/g)
  $('ul').html('');
  tags.forEach(function(tag){
    $('ul').append('<li>' + tag + '</li>')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>

<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Thanku So much! Hoping dis will help me.

Comment: Sir, Could you please help me how to add the anchor tag for #data and also add/remove the anchor tag while merging and spliting the words.

Comment: You could simply change the `<li></li>` to an anchor tag and add your `href` and other attributes as necessary. It will automatically add / remove tags depending on the textarea value.

Comment: Sir, Please go through the below link https://plnkr.co/edit/DSHKEcOnBXi54KyiMpaT?p=preview                   This is not working with textarea as we can't add '<a>' tag in textarea. so i used contenteditable. how could i do merging/spliting the tags  and also  add a hash tag anywhere in the content. All hash Tag must be inside the "<a>" tag.